# Format datepicker not change angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have define the format for my datepicker like this

```
    $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
  };
  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyyMMdd'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[1];
  $scope.dt = new Date();
  $scope.dt2 = new Date();
  console.log($scope.dt);
  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };

  $scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };
```

but when i console.log, the result becoming like this
[image]

i want something like when i console.log the result will be same as i define. for example `Tue Nov 14 2017` into `20171114`

here is my .html file

```
<div class="col-md-2">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt2" is-open="popup2.opened"/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: uib-datepicker-popup="{{formats}}" should be uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"  ? without a 's'

Comment: i have change it, but its still the same

Comment: I saw you did console.log($scope.dt) right after new Date(). Is it the only place you did console.log ?

Comment: @Charlie Ng ya, because i want to know the value of scope.dt

Comment: but $scope.dt is the one without format, don't you want to do console.log($scope.format) instead ?

Comment: if i console log scope.format the result is yyyyMMdd, its not the value what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works for me, hope it helps

```
var d = new Date($scope.dt);
  var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
  var curr_Month = d.getMonth()+1;
          if (curr_Month.toString().length < 2) {
            var curr_Month = "0" + (d.getMonth()+1);
          } else {
            var curr_Month = d.getMonth()+1;
          }
          //alert(curr_Month);

          var curr_date = d.getDate();
          if (curr_date.toString().length<2) {
            var curr_date = "0"+ d.getDate();
          } else {
            var curr_date = d.getDate();
          }
          //alert(curr_date);
          var todayDate = (curr_year + "" + (curr_Month) + "" + curr_date);
```